# The ad unit ID must be set on InterstitialAd before loadAd is called Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

Firstly, sorry for my bad English.

When I build apk and try opening apk in my phone, it gives `apk has stoped working. The ad unit ID must be set on InterstitialAd before loadAd is called` Error.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9823610014389662~4002090629");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9823610014389662/2024107626");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
        }

    });
}

public void displayInterstitial() {

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `logcat` is pointing that the problem is arising only because of Interstitial ads then try this:

Much simpler & tested way - which fills ad request 95-98% times

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;
```

Then put it inside `onCreate()`

```
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.your_interstitial_string_name);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I prefer calling it `onBackPressed()`, you can fit it to your requirement.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.show();
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed();
                    finish();
                }
            });
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Also, don't forget to put String Values in your `strings.xml` file

```
<string name="your_interstitial_string_name">ca-app-pub-9823610014389662/2024107626</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first put String Value in your `string.xml` file which is in the `res>values` folder

`<string name="YourInterstitialAdID">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>`

Then put it your java class.

A method has been created called `loadInterstitialAd();` which is given below `OnCreate` . Please copy paste step by step.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        


        loadInterstitialAd();


        
        
    }//OnCreate Method End


     private void loadInterstitialAd(){

        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        InterstitialAd.load(this, getString(R.string.YourInterstitialAdID), adRequest2,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");


                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");

                                loadInterstitialAd();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                                // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                // show it a second time.
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });


    }



}//MainActivity Class End
```

Finally I prefer calling it `OnBackPressed()`, which put below `OnCreate` method, you can fit it to your requirement.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the accepted answer?